# How many students are in the class if every student is represented in the survey?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A Java Class had $34$ students who passed calculus, $26$ students who passed statistics and $19$ students who passed both calculus and statistics. How many students are in the class if every student is represented in the survey? I have answered this and I was just wondering if my answer is correct.

Let $C$ be the set of students who passed calculus.

Let $S$ be the set of students who passed statistics.

Let $C \cap S$ be the set of students who passed calculus and statistics.

Let $x$ be the number of students in class.

\begin{align*}
|x| & =|C|+|S|−|C \cap S|\\
    & = 34+26-19\\
    & = 41
\end{align*}
Also, am I using the variables correctly? What would you change?

Comment: it's correct. no change needed i think.

Comment: Looks good.  Not sure I'd change anything...maybe add the line $|X|=|C\cup S|$ but that's a very small point.

Comment: thank you, are the variables correctly used?

Comment: i see, thank you for replying :)

Comment: I would leave off the bars around the "x" since it is a number, not a set; and I'm not sure why you have the (1) on the first line.

Comment: @user84413 oh that 1 is a mistake. so you're saying that i should leave it at that? just x and not put bars beside it?

Comment: Yes, I would write $x=|C\cup S|=|C|+|S|-|C\cap S|$ for the first line.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i will, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

community wiki answer so this question can be closed

Your work is correct.  As others have stated in the comments, it would be more illuminating to write 
$$|C \cup S| = |C| + |S| - |C \cap S|$$
since you are using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: how to close this question?

Comment: To close the question, you can award a "best answer" by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.  See [this Help Center page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.  I opted to post a community answer to indicate that I was not taking credit for answering your question, as it had already been answered satisfactorily by you and the people who commented on your answer.   Community wiki questions and answers do not affect your [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and the privileges that accrue with a higher reputation.